# Cannot Connect with TOAD but Can with Other Tools/Apps

Tags: oracle, database-connection, sqlplus, toad

I am able to connect to an Oracle database using several tools, but am unable to connect using Toad for Oracle 8.5.3 (*though before a login/logout to Windows I was able to*).

I am not using **TNSNAMES.ORA** to connect. I have two Oracle homes:

> `C:\Oracle\product\10.2.0\client_1
>   (OraClient10g_home1)` and
>   `C:\Oracle\product\10.2.0\client_2`
>   (ODACHome2)

where client 2 was installed after client 1.

I have tried Toad with each home, but I get "ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified" when I supply the database name, user name, and password. I can connect using SQL*Plus using this same information, and I can connect via ADO.NET (ODP.NET). **tnsping** (client 2) to the server works, but **tnsping** (client 1) does not.

My **PATH** environment variable contains, in order:

> `C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\client_2\bin;C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\client_1\bin`

and changing the order of **PATH** seems to have no effect. When I added the line

> `NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH= (LDAP, TNSNAMES)`

to **sqlnet.ora** of client 2, Toad still could not connect, but the error message appeared much more quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer rather quickly after I posted, but I don't know if this is the best solution. I copied the **ldap.ora** file from client 1 to client 2. **ldap.ora** had lines like the following, which I have munged for security reasons:

> ```
> DIRECTORY_SERVERS= (XXXXX:389:636,YYYYY:389:636)
>
> DEFAULT_ADMIN_CONTEXT = ""
>
> DIRECTORY_SERVER_TYPE = OID
> ```